# UWP unit testing with Jenkins

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, msbuild, uwp, continuous-integration

It is not really an issue I would like to ask today but I search best practices to unit testing a UWP application with Jenkins.

First, I created a Unit Test App for my main application and, on my development machine, I generated appx package using MSBuild command line tool. It works well and I can also execute unit tests with the VS Test console.
Then I tried to automate it with Jenkins on my build server. But the MSBuild command does not work. I have no issue but it produces no output. After lot of research (without any success), my question is the following:

What is the best way to make UWP unit testing with a result dashboard using Jenkins?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a solution now?

Answer (score 0):

In order to make MSBuild work correctly, I had to create two subsequent build steps, one with command line argument:

**-t:restore**

in order to make it restore all the nuget dependencies, and a second one with command line arguments:

**/t:Rebuild  /p:Configuration=Release
/p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload**

for the real release compilation and the creation of both sideload and storeUpload msix files